How can I suppress my iPhone from reporting that a BLE device has re-connected
I am developing a .NET Maui application and using Shiny's BLE implementation to connect to a BLE health tracker band. Everything works fine, but if I background the app and then walk away from my phone, I get the following popup:

The text reads:

The "BleDeviceName" accessory disconnected. Open "MyAppName" to reconnect.

As far as I know I'm not explicitly doing anything to show this popup, unless Shiny BLE is doing it automatically.
Is there a setting that I can provide to my app to prevent this popup from coming up (perhaps in info.plist)?

It seems that that library is setting CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey option to true. Either work out how to change this, or you may want to enable the Bluetooth background mode for your app to enable it to interact with your BLE peripheral while in the background.
